# Route navigation info from Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently able to use the Google Maps API to get a route from point A to point B by using the `google.maps.DirectionsService`. But one thing I cannot seem to get is the actual navigation information (like the one you get when you are on the navigation mode in your cell phone).
Is there any way to get data for things like "turn right in 500 feet on 5th Avenue" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may print these instructions by defining the `panel`-option of the `DirectionsRenderer`(expects to be a HTML-element where to print the instructions).

Demo: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

---

To get single instructions you must iterate over the [steps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#DirectionsStep) of a route and access the `instructions`-property.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the instructions under the route->leg object. Thanks for that!